# How to configure a firewall on Centos using Vagrant and Chef

Tags: virtual-machine, centos, iptables, vagrant, chef

I've created a server box using Vagrant and Chef and everything is up and running correctly. However, when the box is installed from scratch the default iptables rules are in place and so I need to disable the firewall in order to access my web server.

(This is a local VM btw so I don't care about firewall security).

On launching the VM I ssh to it and flush the iptables, which works fine. But what I would prefer is to run a shell script when the machine is created to do this.

Even better I would like configure the iptables using a recipe but I don't see a supported cookbook.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to set the firewall rules in CentOS is to replace the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` entirely by using a template in the recipe.

Say you want to adjust the routing because you are setting up an Apache web server ("apache2") cookbook. Create the file `cookbooks/apache2/templates/default/iptables.erb` with following content:

```
# Firewall configuration created and managed by Chef
# Do not edit manually
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Be sure and have a line return after the COMMIT.

Then call the template in your recipe, and afterward restart the `iptables` service.

```
#
# Load firewall rules we know works
#
template "/etc/sysconfig/iptables" do
  # path "/etc/sysconfig/iptables"
  source "iptables.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 00600
  # notifies :restart, resources(:service => "iptables")
end

execute "service iptables restart" do
  user "root"
  command "service iptables restart"
end
```

When you run `vagrant up`, you will see the following output (excerpt).

```
...
INFO: Processing template[/etc/sysconfig/iptables] action create (bpif_apache2::default line 40)
INFO: template[/etc/sysconfig/iptables] backed up to /var/chef/backup/etc/sysconfig/iptables.chef-20130312055953
INFO: template[/etc/sysconfig/iptables] updated content
INFO: template[/etc/sysconfig/iptables] owner changed to 0
INFO: template[/etc/sysconfig/iptables] group changed to 0
INFO: template[/etc/sysconfig/iptables] mode changed to 600
INFO: Processing execute[service iptables restart] action run (bpif_apache2::default line 49)
INFO: execute[service iptables restart] ran successfully
...
```

The following links helped me grok and finally solve this problem.

- https://github.com/pdaether/LAMP-CentOS-with-Vagrant/blob/master/files/iptables.txt
- http://infrastructure.fedoraproject.org/csi/security-policy/en-US/html/HostIptables-Standard-Introduction-Prerequisites.html

FWIW, Opscode seems to be to find the firewalls in CentOS a bit of a challenge, too, as per their apache2 cookbook README (Feb 23, 2013):

> The easiest but certainly not ideal way to deal with IPtables is to
>   flush all rules. Opscode does provide an iptables cookbook but is
>   migrating from the approach used there to a more robust solution
>   utilizing a general "firewall" LWRP that would have an "iptables"
>   provider. Alternately, you can use ufw, with Opscode's ufw and
>   firewall cookbooks to set up rules. See those cookbooks' READMEs for
>   documentation.